# from Spring boot properties to Hashmap

Tags: spring

What is the best way to load following data from properties files to following hasmap in Spring boot so that
key = us.10004251 and
value = Config class (city = San Diego, state California)

```
us.10004251.city=San Diego
us.10004251.state=California
ca.1212234.city=Toronto
ca.1212234.state=Ontario

Map<String, Config> configurations;

class Config{
  String city;
  String state;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the annotation `@ConfigurationProperties` and `@Configuration` for this purpose.

> `@Configuration` indicating that an object is a source of bean definitions.

> `@ConfigurationProperties` for bind some external Properties (e.g. from a .properties file).

#### Create a class/record that with your values (city, states...)

```java
public record MyConfig(String city, String state) { /* ... */ }

// Or

public class MyConfig {
    private String city;
    private String state;
 
    // getter & setter

    @Override
    public String toString() {
      return "MyConfig{" +
          "city='" + city + '\'' +
          ", state='" + state + '\'' +
          '}';
    }
  }
```

#### Create a class to load your configurations

Create a class to load your properties from the `appplication.properties` (or other) file for store them in the `Map`.

- Define the `@Configuration` annotation to indicate its role as a Spring configuration class.
- Apply the `@ConfigurationProperties` annotation to enable binding of properties from the applications.properties file. You can specify a prefix in `@ConfigurationProperties`, in this case "my" is the prefix, so that Spring injects properties from the configuration file that start with "my" into this class.
- Creates a field containing the `Map` with properties loaded and create the getter for this field

```java
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "my")
public class TestConfiguration {
  private final Map<String, MyConfig> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();

  public Map<String, MyConfig> getMap() {
    return this.map;
  }
 
  public void debug() { 
    if (this.map.isEmpty()) System.out.println("map is empty");
    else this.map.forEach((k, v) -> System.out.println(k + " => " + v)); 
  }
}
```

#### Add your properties to your applications.properties file.

You need to surround your key by `[]` to preserve its original value **OR** any characters that are not alpha-numeric, - or . are removed. binding map. [see: doc binding map](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config.typesafe-configuration-properties.relaxed-binding.maps)

Syntax: `[prefix].[fieldName].[key].[fieldName]=value`

```
my.map.[us.10004251].city=San Diego
my.map.[us.10004251].state=California
my.map.[ca.1212234].city=Toronto
my.map.[ca.1212234].state=Ontario
```

Note: ".map." in the properties key refers to the name of the field in the TestConfiguration$map class (`Map<String, MyConfig> map = ...`)

## Use your configuration in your service, component, controller, etc.

```java
public class IndexController {
  
  public IndexController(TestConfiguration cfg) { 
    cfg.debug(); // use the configuration
  }
 
}
```

Example of the output obtained after calling the debugging method:

```
us.10004251 => MyConfig[city=San Diego, state=California]
ca.1212234 => MyConfig[city=Toronto, state=Ontario]
```

You can find more information here:
[docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config)

Comment: actually map is not mandatory. If change this variable something other then map then its works - private final Map<String, BankConfig> map= new LinkedHashMap<>(); But thank you work the solution!

Comment: is there way to validate that info is present in properties files and prevent application from booting up? And is that good practis?

Comment: You can do this with jakarta validation, here's an example I've just published in gist
example: [gist.github.com](https://gist.github.com/tmslpm/eb63eb30b09a868a9e1592e460a5c501). I don't know whether this is good practice or not

Comment: thanks again, it works.  Just don't understand now in what cases I have to use Validated and when Valid